# Transaction reverted: trying to deploy a contract whose code is too large

Tags: hardhat, testing, testnets, hardhat-deploy, chai

My smart contract is over 300 lines of code, complete with events, modifiers, internal functions, getters and setters.

I'm trying to run tests using hardhat and chai. All I'm getting is this error:
`Error: cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit`

`"Transaction reverted: trying to deploy a contract whose code is too large"`

Like, what the hell? When I run my deploy script to Mumbai testnet, I also get an error although different:

How can I make this smart contract build with so much code in it?

`npx hardhat --network polygonMumbai run scripts\runTradable.ts`

result:

```
Deploying contracts with the account: 0x85efe474EfD954021A9562ca6A0AC5eD8679DEbF
Account balance: 3.75318680580021
Network: polygonMumbai
ProviderError: HttpProviderError
    at HttpProvider.request
```

What I would like:

- Make the contract build without all the unnecessary code, if any.
- Get rid of the error: `cannot estimate gas; transaction may fail or may require manual gas limit` when deploying
- make all tests pass and deploy

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this case, the problem was the mal-formed `hardhat.config.js` file. Here is what should solve the problem:

```
module.exports = {
  solidity: {
    version: "0.8.9",
    settings: {
      optimizer: {
        enabled: true,
        runs: 1000,
      },
    },
  },
  allowUnlimitedContractSize: true,
  networks: {[...]}
}
```

Comment: In my case I had to include the `allowUnlimitedContractSize` as part of the hardhat network config, and not outside like it shows here

Answer (score 2):

This one is hard to answer without the smart contract code. I guess the compiled bytecode is too large (e.g. [24kb limit in ETH)](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-170.md), You may try to use optimizer when compiling: https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/guides/compile-contracts

Add to the `solidity` field in your `hardhat.config.js`

```
    settings: {
      optimizer: {
        enabled: true,
      },
    },
```

And remember to delete cache and compile again : `npx hardhat compile --force`

I will update this answer if I get more information

Comment: I have just saw that I had a discrepancy in the hardhat config file! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, it could also be that the contract costs more gas than the limit you set on it, I had a similar problem and I got over it by

1. removing the gas limit and deploying on a local node
2. checking the consumed gas and setting the gas limit to be slightly above consumed gas for contract deployment